# Drag and drop cell content from cell to cell i EXCEL 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have a quite huge and complex application based mainly on vba (+7500 lines of code): Its importing and analyzing the wishes for each teacher in my school (also written in Excel). And then, the administrator can edit whatever setting/wish so next year planning of the teacher resources are complete.

It works quite well. And functions almost like a database.

My 'concern':

The user (administrator) changes the position of the many 'brics' all the time:
I've illustrated it in this first image from one of many sheets:*matter/classes/teacher*. The red arrow shows the blue **LN - 2** bric is dragged one position to the right: the class is changed from **1A** to **1B** for the matter (*fag* in danish) **DAF**.

[image: The way we do it now. We need to go to the border the be able to move the cell]

It is working well, but my concern is for the user: everytime he want to move a bric, he has to

1. select the cell (that is all right) and then
2. 'reach' the border of the cell - cursor change (move+arrow) as seen - before the dragging can be done.

I would like to find a way of dragging directly the bric, so the **user shouldn't go to the border** before it can be dragged. This next - allmost identical - image shows this wish: the cursor - cross - is in the middle of the cell, is clicked and dragged to the neighbor cell.

[image: The wish way: remark the cursor is 'somewhere' in the middle of the cell]

'Normally' you can't do it with the ordinary events (that I use extensively), but maybe somebody knows of a clever method/library to obtain this goal.

**EDIT:**

Just to be exact: the bric need to be dragged in whatever direction, whatever distance, not only: one to the right (only an example)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code below to your worksheet's code, to the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event, so the user can move the cell to the right when he double-clicks the cell (and not the border).

**Code** (inside the worksheet module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If MsgBox("Do you want to drag the cell to the right ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Target.Cut Destination:=Target.Offset(, 1)       
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but it was only an example about one to the right. I need to drag a 'bric' to whatever position on the chart: up, down, left, right and whatever distance needed.